# Why is Sorbonne ranked higher than Polytechnique in mathematics?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

Looking at the rankings, I saw that Sorbonne and Paris-Saclay are usually ranked higher than ENS and Polytechnique in the field of mathematics. This came as a surprise to me since it's well known that the latter are way more selective than the former.

I get the argument that studying at university the  gives you more freedom of thought than grinding for two years in a *prépa* because the subjects are more open and you get to interact with actual researchers (your teachers).

However it's a fact that *prépas* (which are the way to enter an engineer school such as Polytechnique or ENS) are very hard, in spite (or perhaps because) of their strict highschool-like format.

My take is that in the field of mathematics, especially if your goal is to do research, there's no point in grinding for two years in a *prépa* and that a more appropriate approach is to slowly build knowledge doing licence/bachelor at university; so that might be the reason Sorbonne is ranked higher than the *Écoles*.

Is there a stronger reason for this?

Comment: One needs to look at how the rankings are determined, and then think whether any of those criteria matter. Generally, the criteria are things that can be scored easily, not things that actually matter.

Comment: This is a silly ranking for undergraduates.  If you want to become a mathematician, go to ENS.  My French colleagues tell me that something like half of all MdCs and professeur(e)s in mathematics in French universities went to one of the four ENSs.

Comment: The rankings are mostly based on the research outputs of the departments, and both of the grandes ecoles have smaller departments that are dedicated (for the rank and file teaching staff) to more intensive teaching.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo MdC?

Comment: MdC: Maître de Conférence, roughly the equivalent of Assistant Professor in the US system

Comment: Those international rankings compare, by design, institutions that are located in very different academic systems and cultures. This is obviously prone to produce a lot of non-sensical results.

Comment: How would you compare Sorbonne/Saclay and the Écoles ?

Comment: "My take is that in the field of mathematics, especially if your goal is to do research, there's no point in grinding for two years in a prépa and that a more appropriate approach is to slowly build knowledge doing licence/bachelor at university; so that might be the reason Sorbonne is ranked higher than the Écoles." That definitely isn't the reason why it's ranked higher. The reason why it's ranked higher is that if you sum all the points in all the categories of the ranking, Sorbonne ends up with a higher number than the Ecoles. Not anything to do with "slowly building knowledge" etc.

Comment: Which ranking are you referring to?

Comment: @Allure QS, Shanghai.